# Create new table with productions by hour

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to transform a table. I have the data frame ByBatch:

```
Batch      Time              DurationHours     UnitsProduced
  1     2015-04-03 13:00          4                2500
  2     2015-04-04 14:00          3                1500
```

I need to transform that table to one with production by hour and batch (ByHour):

```
Time               Batch      UnitsProduced
2015-04-03 13:00      1         625
2015-04-03 14:00      1         625
2015-04-03 15:00      1         625
2015-04-03 16:00      1         625
2015-04-04 14:00      2         500
2015-04-03 15:00      2         500
2015-04-03 16:00      2         500
```

I was thinking about applying a for loop and apply function but this seems to be very complicated and maybe not a good approach. I would appreciate if anyone could provide me just a guidelines about a good approach to this.

Comment: this link should help you to do what you want http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/

Comment: your example is not reproducible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to loop through the rows of the input data frame (`dat` here), generating a data frame with the desired output rows corresponding to that input row. I do the looping with `lapply` here, generating a list of data frames, one per input row. All that remains is to combine all those generated data frames together into a single output data frame, which I do with `do.call` and `rbind`.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(dat), function(i) {
  data.frame(Time = dat$Time[i] + 3600*(0:(dat$DurationHours[i]-1)),
             Batch = dat$Batch[i],
             UnitsProduced = dat$UnitsProduced[i] / dat$DurationHours[i])
}))
#                  Time Batch UnitsProduced
# 1 2015-04-03 13:00:00     1           625
# 2 2015-04-03 14:00:00     1           625
# 3 2015-04-03 15:00:00     1           625
# 4 2015-04-03 16:00:00     1           625
# 5 2015-04-04 14:00:00     2           500
# 6 2015-04-04 15:00:00     2           500
# 7 2015-04-04 16:00:00     2           500
```

Data:

```
dat = data.frame(Batch=1:2, Time=strptime(c("2015-04-03 13:00", "2015-04-04 14:00"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), DurationHours=c(4, 3), UnitsProduced=c(2500, 1500))
```